# How can I load an applescript file from bundle using swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, applescript

I'm trying to have swift load an applescript file from bundle. However, unless I use a place like my desktop, which relies on my username, it won't read it. If I program it to get it from my desktop, then I can't share it with people. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a POSIX path with shorthand?

```
~/Desktop
```

~/ is shorthand for the current user

Comment: No. I get this error. osascript: ~/Desktop/iMessageSpam.scpt: No such file or directory